# bootstrap navbar collapses weirdly in safari

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-plugins, navigation

I am very new at this field, so forgive me if I couldn't define the problem properly. Frankly I am not sure how to describe it so I uploaded a video of the problem. So here it is: https://youtu.be/w9dyBqTQKhc

It's all okay in Chrome and Firefox. I also use a jquery plugin called "sticky" if that matters.

Edit: When I set transition to none problem disappears but even when I use webkit etc. it comes back. I'd still appreciate help since I wanna keep my nice transitions :)

And here is the html:

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" id="sticker">
        <div class = container> 
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse ">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle nav</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button> 
                <div class="active">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h1>reflections</h1></a>
                </div>
            </div><!--navbar-header-->
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#project">DESCRIPTION</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#team">PHOTOS</a> 
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact">CONTACT US</a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#location">OUR LOCATION</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!---navbar-collapse--->
    </nav>
```

And related css:

```
<style>
.navbar-default {
border:none;
background-color: transparent;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
color:#20D1FF;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
color:#10687F;
}
.is-sticky .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a{
color:#1AA7CC;
font-weight: 600;
}
.is-sticky .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a:hover {
color:#20D1FF;
}
nav ul li a{
color: white;
font-weight: bold;
font-weight: 500;
}
nav ul li {
border-left: 1px solid #000000;
}
#sticker {
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 255);
z-index: 1000;
transition: 0.4s;
height: auto;
    max-height: 50px;
transition: none;
}
.is-sticky #sticker {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
transition: 2s;
max-height: 50px;
transition: none;

}
#sticker li.active a{
background-color: white;
color: #10687F;
font-weight: bolder;
text-shadow: none;
}
header .navbar-brand {
background-position: 0 0;
height: auto;
position: absolute;
margin-top: -10px;
}
header .navbar-brand h1{
color: black;
margin: 0;
font-size:1.8em;
font-weight: 400;
padding-left: 20px;
}
.is-sticky .navbar-brand h1{
color:white;
}
</style>
```

I don't know what else I should post in my message, if there is anything else please tell.

All help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have custom CSS and such going on and we don't know what that looks like. We're going to need all relevant CSS and javascript. A link to the site will assist as well.

Comment: Okay so I've been playing with it and problem was transition. When I set the transition to none problem disappears but even when I use webkit it comes back. I will edit my post and add the css as well. There is barely any JS, just a few lines for active class. And unfortunately site is not online yet.